# how to write arabic in pdf using FPDF ? (php)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

im using using fpdf lib to generate pdf file in englisg language but now im trying generate pdf file in Arabic language so problem is FPDF is supported Arabic or not if suupported then how we generate pdf file in arabic?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$strp_txt = stripslashes("Write your content here");
$strp_txt = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $strp_txt);

$pdf->Write (6, $strp_txt);
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: im add this $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','dejavu-fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf'); and $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 14); so error is pare erorr