# How to display Arabic data in FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using PHP and FPDF to generate a PDF. My problem is, the data is not displaying in Arabic. How to show Arabic data in content of PDF?

Here is my code:

```
require('include/fpdf/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF {

// Page header
function Header()
{

    $this->Image('include/fpdf/tutorial/logo.png',10,6,30);// Logo
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);// Arial bold 15
    $this->Cell(80);// Move to the right
    $this->Cell(30,10,'العنوان',1,0,'C');// Title
    $this->Ln(20);// Line break
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{

    $this->SetY(-15);// Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);// Arial italic 8
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');// Page number
}}


    // Instanciation of inherited class
    $pdf = new PDF();

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

    for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,' تجربة '.$i,0,1);

    $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162814/how-to-write-arabic-in-pdf-using-fpdf-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453728/arabic-script-in-pdf-created-by-ufpdf

Comment: I would use UTF-8, the solution to this is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21530540/3065387

Comment: It is very easy and quite possible!  tFPDF, a branch of the FPDF project, allows you to use UTF-8 in PDF's, take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56429391/2430549

Answer (score 0):

FPDF doesn't support natively UTF-8 characters, but only ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.

You should try to generate your own font, but I don't find that an easy task. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090800/998759) for some help.