# FPDF cannot display japanese word

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf

Now I'm doing a task about exporting data into PDF from CodeIgniter framework. I'm using FPDF http://www.fpdf.org/ for exporting the PDF. And here is my controller:

```
public function exportPDF()
{
    $pdf = new FPDF('l','mm','A4');
    // create new page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    // setting font type
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);

    $pdf->Cell(40,6,'オーダー番号',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,'デリバリー日',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'カスタマー名',1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,6,'住所',1,0); 
    $pdf->Cell(12,6,'数量',1,1);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

    //fetch data
    $res['data'] = $this->session->userdata('logistic_account');
    $data['orderlist'] = $this->Bll_products->exportPDF($res['data']['logistic_id']);

    foreach ($data['orderlist'] as $row) {
        $pdf->Cell(40,6,$row->order_number,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->delivery_date,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row->name,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,$row->address,1,0); 
        $pdf->Cell(12,6,$row->order_quantity,1,1);
    }

    $filename = $res['data']['pic_name']."_".date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.pdf';
    $pdf->Output($filename, 'D');

}
```

But the result like this:

[image]

How do I can display a Japanese word in that .pdf file?

Comment: I believe this can help you. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398045/5721944

Comment: It is very easy and quite possible!  tFPDF allows you to use UTF-8 in PDF's, take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56429391/2430549